# Document hiding using column value in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, calculated-columns

I am calculating one column based on two other column values. If the calculated value is more than 3, then that that document must be hidden in lotus notes view. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't calculate it in columns.

Use the view selection formula to exclude documents.

```
_column1 := ...;
_column2 := ...;
_column3 := _column1 + _column2;
SELECT _column3 <= 3;
```